# Is it possible to have 2 times prepare for segue for 2 different view controllers?

Tags: swift, uibutton, segue

I am swift beginner and I am struggling with my first application. Sorry if my question is too basic, but I get an error message in my code here:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    let secVC: NavigationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NavigationViewController // here is the error
    secVC.receiveImeNaSladkarnica = Label1.text!
    secVC.KordaA = Shirina.text!
    secVC.KordaB = Duljina.text!
    secVC.PodImeNaObekt = Label2.text!
```

I have created 2 different buttons: Navi Me and More Info buttons.

The first one (Navi Me) is connected with another view controller which is called NavigationViewContorller, there I send all of the data I need by using prepare for segue. Everything was working perfect, but now I have created another button which is called (MoreInfo).It is connected with 3rd viewcontroller called MoreInfoViewController. I think I have connected everything fine, but still when I click on the MoreInfo button the app stops working and I get the following error: Thread 1: signal SIGBART in the marked line. I cannot understand why is it breaking when this segue is for another view controller, nt for the MoreInfoViewController. Would you please advice me what to do or provide me with an example how to fix it

I have tried that:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    switch segue.identifier {
 //error here->       case "VC1" :
        let secVC: NavigationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! NavigationViewController
        secVC.receiveImeNaSladkarnica = Label1.text!
        secVC.KordaA = Shirina.text!
        secVC.KordaB = Duljina.text!
        secVC.PodImeNaObekt = Label2.text!

  //error here ->       case "VC2" :
        let secVC2: MoreInfoViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MoreInfoViewController
        secVC2.receiveImeNaSladkarnica = Label1.text!
        secVC2.KordaA = Shirina.text!
        secVC2.KordaB = Duljina.text!
        secVC2.PodImeNaObekt = Label2.text!

    default:
        break
```

It still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each segue is supposed to have an unique string identifier.
For multiple view controllers use a `switch` statement

```
switch segue.identifier {
    case "vc1" : 
       // prepare to go to vc1
    case "vc2" : 
       // prepare to go to vc2
    default : break
}
```

Once again my yesterday comment:

*Since you are a beginner in Swift please learn first to consider the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter.*

Comment: But I haven't started preparing it for segue yet. I just wanted to see is it opening the MoreInfoViewController and the app stops working and give me this error.I mean I will do that, but is it possible to see the empty view controller when I click the button

Comment: If `prepareForSegue` is called from different locations to go to different view controllers you have to distinguish the cases like I suggested.

Comment: Thank you I will try it out now

Comment: I have tried it, but I get an error in the updated code. The error says: Pattern   of type string cannot match value of type string?